# Writing a test case for a condition where the data is an array that generates many data using a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, testing

This is the function that is in the mockData folder

```
export const generateNotificationMockMany = (count) => (
    [...new Array(count)].map((index) => ({
            'group': `group number ${index}`,
            'message': `msg for group number ${index}`,
            'datetime': '',
        }),
    ));
```

this is the test case I've been trying to write. the data is being imported from a file that has this function in it that generates the mockdata. How can I write the test case for it? basically how can I use a loop to be able to get access to all the generated data by the function?

```
it('renders properly for the many variant', ()=> {
        render(<NotificationMenu notifications={notificationsMock}/>)

    });
```

Comment: Do you want to run a separate test case (`it()`) for every item in the mocks array ?

Comment: not necessarily for every item but I want to use some sort of loop for the randomly generated Array that will test all of them. the Objects in the array are almost identical with the difference of the index number as you see.

Answer (score 0):

Does one of the following options solve your problem, or do you expect something else ?

loop over test cases:

```
const mocks = generateNotificationMockMany(10);

for (let notificationsMock of mocks) {
  it(`renders properly for the variant ${notificationsMock}`, ()=> {
    render(<NotificationMenu notifications={notificationsMock}/>)
  });
}
```

loop inside test case:

```
const mocks = generateNotificationMockMany(10);

it(`renders properly for the many variant`, ()=> {
  for (let notificationsMock of mocks) {
    render(<NotificationMenu notifications={notificationsMock}/>)
  }
});
```